# Delete an object with a large number of CASCADE models on Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I am running into an issue where I cannot delete user accounts with Django.

The problem is that there are several other models in code that have the field:

```
user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

These models themselves have other models that are set to be deleted with `on_delete=models.CASCADE` when they are deleted.

So when I try to delete a user that had a lot of activity on my website, it can quickly become tens of thousands of items to delete. This causes the delete operation to never end and the account to not get deleted. Worse, only some of the content gets deleted as the operation is interrupted.

How should I handle deleting a model with many CASCADE delete linked to it?

I am using `Django 3.1` with a MySQL db.

Comment: Normally a `CASCADE` waill not take that much time, since it will not remove one element at a time, but remove related items in bulk. So if a `Car` object depends on a user, it will make a query to look for *all* cars relate to that user, and then delete all these `Car` objects in a single query. If there is a `Tire` object that depends on `Car`s it will make two extra queries: one to fetch all related `Tire`s and one to remove all these `Tire`s, but thus for such "transitive" cascade, it still adds only ~two database calls per cascade relation.

Comment: As for large operations, you should use an mechanism like rabbitMQ. In that case for a delete of a user, you create a message, and then let that message perform a Django management command, which can take a lot of time, and is thus not limited to the request timeout.

Comment: As Willem already stated these operations can take good amount of time, Django does not use database CASCADE but its own emulation which is somewhat good enough alternative. Larger deletions should be converted into tasks that will not timeout on request.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.CASCADE
https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/deletion.py#L23
https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/21961

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Do you have an example of how to implement this? Do I have to bypass the django ORM and manually look for all the related objects to delete them myself?

Comment: Just to rule out the obvious: you're not doing this in the admin are you? Cause rendering the items that are about to be deleted does take a crap load of time.

Comment: @Melvyn No, that's a line calling `request.user.delete()`